# How to open any input file whether it contains words or numbers and prints it out. C++

Tags: c++, file, text-files

So Lets say this is what the input file contains

12

Hello

45

54

100

Cheese

23

How would I print it out on the screen in that order.
This is what I had but it skips some lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    string word;
    int loop = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("arraynumbers.txt");
    while(infile >> number >> word)
    {
        if( infile >> number)
        {
            cout << number << endl;
        }
        if(infile >> word)
        {
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing some basic concepts here. You need to parse one line you read from a file into strings and numbers. What you're trying to do does not achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) to answer these questions.

However, you are on the right track.  Since you are just outputting the contents of the file to stdout, I suggest using readline() and a string.  If you need to access the numeric strings as ints, use the atoi() function.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file("arraynumber.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    } else cout << "Error opening arraynumber.txt: File not found in current directory\n";
    return 0;
```